# transaction flow with roll back strategy mule

Tags: soap, mule, mule-component, mule-el, anypoint-studio

Input:-

```
<balanceInquiry>
    <request>
      <amount>
        <amount>5.0</amount>
        <currency/>
      </amount>
    </request>
  </balanceInquiry>
<balanceInquiry>
    <request>
      <amount>
        <amount>10.0</amount>
        <currency/>
      </amount>
    </request>
  </balanceInquiry>
<balanceInquiry>
    <request>
      <amount>
        <amount>57.0</amount>
        <currency/>
      </amount>
    </request>
  </balanceInquiry>
```

I am trying to hit a SOAP webservice using the above input, but the webservice can only accept one balanceInquiry request at once. So I am spliting the request into different balanceInquiry using splitter. but if the status of 1st request is success then I have to go for 2nd and so on. If anyone of them fails then I need to rollback all the previous transaction. there is a attribute  which can be "success" or "fail" depending on the request.

So I want to know if there is any component to achieve this in mule? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should take a look at the foreach documentation.   https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/foreach and the exception handling strategy ; https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/error-handling.

If your 3 inquiries are in the same message and that you are using the default exception strategy, it will rollback the previous transactions... assuming you are writing the SOAP responses in a database using a DB connector.

Since I don't know exactly what you wish to do in your transaction, here's another interesting link : https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/rollback-exception-strategy

Comment: Is there a way to come out of for each, in case of any trasaction failure. I have implemented foreach and I am getting all the proper responses. There is a attribute in the response <status> which can be either success or fail. If it is success, i need to proceed for other transaction if it is fail then i need to stop there and void the previous transactions... So in case its fail, is there a way to come out of foreach???